# Passing variable to middleware in laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to send a VARIABLE to my middleware in laravel ,the way I tried  is this

```
Route::get('projects/{id}','projectsController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'project:{id}']);
```

But all I get in the middleware handle function is `'{id}'` where as I want the value of the id variable

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next,$pid)
{
    dd($pid);
    return $next($request);
}
```

I  read the documentation on middleware for the version of laravel I am using i.e. 5.2 https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

But the example given there only talks about passing plain strings as parameters

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out , looks like you don't need to pass query pararmets like this, you can simply pull them using the $request variable like so :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $pid=$request->id;

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for coming back and answering your own question.  This was very helpful.